# Internet Explorer ugly CSS transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am creating an animated sidebar for a website. It looks just as I want it in every browser except in Internet Explorer it looks ugly. I tried to enable hardware acceleration but it didn't solve the issue.
Click on the "more information" on the top left of the screen in Internet Explorer to see the bug.
Thanks for any suggestions!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-inner">
            <button id="more-info">More Information</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="background-rectangle"></div>
    <div id="background-triangle"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9999999999;
}
#background-rectangle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 999999999;
}
#background-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 40vw;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50vh solid transparent;
    border-left: 10vw solid rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    border-bottom: 50vh solid transparent;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 999999999;
}
#background-rectangle.active {
    width: 45vw;
}
#background-triangle.active {
    left: 45vw;
   border-left: 0vw solid rgba(0,0,0,.7) !important;
}
#info {
    padding: 0px 5%;
    left: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    height: inherit;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    color: rgb(90,90,100);
    transition: all 1s;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#info.active {
    left: 45vw;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#more-info').click(function() {
        $( '#background-rectangle' ).toggleClass('active');
        $( '#background-triangle' ).toggleClass('active');
        $( '#info' ).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the line that appears, because it only appears to show once per page refresh.

Comment: To get universally smooth CSS animations, limit your transitions to `transform` and `opacity`. Instead of resizing your elements with `border`, `width` and `left`, you could use `transform: scale()` and `transform: translateX()`. Read more here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am going to try the scaling method!

Comment: I changed the CSS but as soon as I apply `transform: scaleX()` there is a pixel bug in some resolutions. Meanwhile I got an idea I shouldn't use borders to create the triangles at all, two rectangles with `transform: skew()` is a better approach